# Assign a class on body conditionally in Jade

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, pug, gulp

Assume I have main template file named `layout.jade` and a bunch of files that extend this template - `home`, `about`, `products` and so on.

In main template I put structure like this:

```
    body
        section.main-content
            block content
```

Then pages:

```
    extends ../layouts/default
    block content
        include partials/banner
        include partials/why
```

So different pages put different content into content block accordingly. I render pages with `gulp-jade` and in the end I have all the pages as HTML.

My question is - can I put some variable inside child page, like `about`, so that it to go as a class to body tag of its parent template, like `<body class="about">`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a pattern I use for this type of situation. In your main template, set up some variables:

```
//layouts/default.jade
- var bodyClass;
block variables
html
  head
  body(class=bodyClass)
    section.main-content
      block content
```

Then establish the `bodyClass` in your page templates.

```
//about.jade
extends ../layouts/default
block variables
  - bodyClass = "about"
block content
  h1 This is the About Page
```

This is how I do my page titles for the `<head><title>` tag, for example. I can also have logic in the `layout.jade` file to provide default values, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the simple solution!